# Zxing CustomOverlay MVVMCross

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, zxing

I have Zxing barcode scanning with custom layout working with the fragments. So I was wondering is it possible to make it work from a viewmodel instead of a fragment? Thank You.